# How to get the value of css property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I face here a really stupid worries, but I can not solve it.

When the mouse hovers the `panel`, I would like to change the background with the color associated to the current panel.

Here is the HTML (using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)) :

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h3 class="text-center">Text</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS :

```
$('.panel').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'color' : '#fff',
        'background-color' : $('.panel-primary.border-color') // This makes no sense, but I don't see how to do it
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css({
        'color' : '#000',
        'background-color' : '#fff'
    });
});
```

Example in this case :

The css class `panel-primary` and its color is `#428bca` (defined in the file `bootstrap.css`). Therefore, I would like to understand how to obtain this color in the CSS file, and be able to apply it directly with jQuery in the code above.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/7qbenfuk/)

Is it possible ? How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery allows you to retrieve CSS information of any element using `.css('property-name')`.

```
$(".panel-primary").css('border-color');
```

This should do just fine.

Comment: Ok, I took the lead for nothing. Yet it was very simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.css` property to fetch the css property of the panel & then set the same to the background.

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.panel').mouseenter(function () {
  var panelColor = $('.panel-primary').css('border-color');
  console.log("col:" + panelColor);
  $(this).css({
    'color': '#fff',
        'background-color': panelColor
  });
}).mouseleave(function () {
   $(this).css({
    'color': '#000',
        'background-color': '#fff'
   });
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/7qbenfuk/1/)